# Not able to commit in github: not able to connect port 443

Tags: git, github, ssh, ubuntu-14.04, ssh-keys

I am new to github. I use Ubuntu 14.04. I have been trying to commit my first project to github but I got an error :

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/tibrewalricha/myproject.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Network is unreachable
```

I was following the [Install Github](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-configure-and-use-git-on-ubuntu/) tutorial to install github. When I wrote the command `git push origin master`, I got the above error.

I have upgraded git, even reinstalled it. But I get the same error again and again.

Comment: use ssh. You can't use `ssh` keys on `https` urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ssh`. You can't use `ssh` keys on `https` urls.

Change the line in your `.git/config` repository URL from

```
url = https://github.com/tibrewalricha/myproject.git/
```

to

```
url = git@github.com:tibrewalricha/myproject.git
```

and repeat the push. It should solve the issue for you.

Comment: This should do the same. But checking in the config file would not hurt.

Comment: I am getting the following error : Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights

Comment: Yes. Your tutorial provides only `https` setup, which is blocked in your network. Check [github guide](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/). After going through that steps, you shuold be able to push.